# Вывод таблиц базы происходит через ajax. Как выводить не все столбцы?

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Имеется список таблиц из базы данных в виде `<ul><li>...` при клике на каждую из них ajax'ом выводится их содержимое в виде `<table><tr>...`. Эти таблицы имеют разное количество столбцов, но почти у каждой таблицы есть столбцы userID (номер пользователя, который сейчас вошел) и id (номер записи текущего пользователя).

Как выводить данные содержимое таблиц так, 1) чтобы я видел заголовок столбцов сверху 2) чтобы не выводился столбец UserID (и возможно id)?

Мой sql-запрос выглядит так:

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM {$arr['tableName']} 
WHERE`UserID`= {$_SESSION['user'][0]}";`

`$arr['tableName']` - это переменная, которая пришла в json из js и стала строкой в php.

Если просто вывести массив из базы, чтобы посмотреть что вообще приходит (пример кода и результат для таблицы с 3 столбцами):

`echo '<pre>';
print_r($result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC));
echo '</pre>';`

Здесь фрагменты значений пользователя с UserID = 1:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [userID] => 1
            [id] => 33
            [item] => с Эдуардом Бендерским
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [userID] => 1
            [id] => 34
            [item] => с Евгением Полонским
        )
)
```

Получается, что для примера, указанного выше я хотел бы видеть (для начала) заголовки id и item, а ниже значения. Действительно ведь зачем пользователю видеть столбец с цифрой "1". И как дать нормальные, впоследствии, названия столбцам на русском, чтобы они появлялись динамически? Благодарю за помощь и критику!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильный вариант - отказаться от `print_r` и выводить все поля руками.

```
$Result = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
foreach($Result as $val)
{
  echo "Идентификатор: {$val['id']}\r\n";
  echo "Предмет      : {$val['item']}\r\n";
}
```

Неправильный вариант - "кастовать" названия полей в MySQL

```
SELECT 
  id as Идентификатор, 
  item as Предмет 
FROM 
  {$arr['tableName']} 
WHERE 
  UserID= {$_SESSION['user'][0]}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ! А как быть с запросом «Select *...»?

Comment: Так же ка и с любым запросом содержащим «*» -  не писать его =)

Comment: Ок, понял Вашу мысль. Но как бы вы поступили на моем месте? Имеется список таблиц и при клику по названию вижу их содержимое. То есть, при клике имеется один и тот же запрос к разным таблицам. Можно конечно сформировать массива ответа на запрос и удалить у него ключи, скажем, UserID... Есть ли альтернатива? Может мой подход изначально неверен. Как бы Вы сделали?

Comment: Лично я? сделал бы правильно =) Изучил документацию, понял бы смысл того что в этом запросе что означает, и после - реализовал ровно так как мне нужно..... Это сейчас у вас одно поле лишнее, а теперь представьте - завтра вам в эту таблицу понадобится добавить еще 10 полей, и любой запрос с * - будет возвращать 10 ненужных полей и 2 нужных, накладные расходы в 90%.... такое себе удовольствие =)

Comment: Ладно, запрос подкорректирую. Ну, а все-таки?)) Если необходимо переключаться между таблицами?

Comment: Вы наверное меня неверно поняли изначально =) Все запросы пишутся с учетом данных которые необходимо выводить... 10 таблиц - 10 запросов(или 10 джоинов, в зависимости от того что нужно и что вы понимаете под словом "переключатся"), и в каждом запросе - только нужная вам информация. писать * в запросе данных - плохой тон, который когда нибудь приведет к появлению ошибок.
Вывод не подготовленной информации через print_r - не в целях отладки - плохой тон...(я с ходу не вспомню ни единого примера где бы мне понадобился вывод через print_r, кроме случаев отладки)

Comment: Если вам нужен универсальный генератор запросов и вывода - так и говорите =) Но в любом случае на вход нужно подавать поля для вывода =)

Comment: Да, print_r был для отладки, я там так и написал "чтобы посмотреть, что приходит")) А под словом "переключаться" я в прямом смысле имею ввиду мышью переключаться по названию таблицы. Ок, я сделаю для 10 таблиц 10 запросов. А что должно быть на стороне сервера? Наверное, странно `if(табл5)`, то запрос такой-то. Я начинающий, поэтому и спрашиваю.

Comment: Ничего странного с клиента передаете ID запроса, пусть это будет число от 0 до 9(10 таблиц же?), на стороне сервера храните массив запросов(строк(от 0 до 9) вида select xxx from yyy....)..... =)

Comment: Понятно, картина прорисовалась)

Comment: Что значит "кастовать"?))

Comment: В общем случае или в частом из ответа? В общем вот https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-RU/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=aps-pdw-2016, в частном - "применить\установить\задать"